# Building tensorflow from source

Tags: python, tensorflow, build, bazel

I am trying to build tensorflow from source by following this [link](https://medium.com/vitrox-publication/deep-learning-frameworks-tensorflow-build-from-source-on-windows-python-c-cpu-gpu-d3aa4d0772d8).

In step 8, I had to modify the configure.py line 482 to hardcode the version of bazel I am using (2.0.0) because the function that was suppose to get it crashed.

Execpt that I have done everything like in the link. In step 9, I need to execute the command **bazel build** and get the following output:

```
>bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
.bazelrc
```

Unfortunaletly, I am unable to find the .whl package that was suppose to be generated by this command.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the above output is in fact saying: "Please run me as administrator privileges".

Could not be more explicit....